# How do I find a function to minimize another function?

Tags: derivatives, optimization

I am given to constants $b, n \in \mathbb{N}$. The task is to find a function $r(b,n)$ such that $\text{range}(r)=[1,b]$ and the value of $\frac{b}{r(b,n)}(n+2^{r(b,n)})$ is minimal. Do I have to necessarily deal with PDE's, or I can reduce the task on setting $r$ constant and finding minimum of $f(r)=\frac{b}{r}(n+2^{r})$ (find roots of derivative and and then expressing $r$ through $b$ and $n$).

My guess is that it should be $r=1$, so we reduce exponential part of the function, but I want to prove this rigorously.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly just minimize $f(r)=\frac br(n+2^r)$ though it might be clearer to define $s=r(b,n)$ and use $s$ to avoid reusing $r$.  You only use $r(b,n)$, so any two functions which agree on those arguments will return the same value for $f(r(b,n))$  You can then define $r(x,y)$ to cover the range of interest:  $[1,b]$.  As you minimize, you need to restrict $r$ to that interval.

The minimum will not depend on $b$ but will depend on $n$.  I don't see an algebraic solution.